# Using Microdata with schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I'm looking at http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification Microdata schema for places (and more). I'm a little bit confused on the value to be used for [DayOfWeek](http://schema.org/DayOfWeek).

Both classes (*OpeningHoursSpecification* and *DayOfWeek*) are derived from the GoodRelations Vocabulary for E-Commerce and I'm not confident with this vocabulary.

Please, can you post a full example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The enumerations (list of predefined values) of the GoodRelations model remain in the GoodRelations namespace, i.e. for Mondays, use

```
http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday
```

Here is a full example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" itemid="#store">
  <span itemprop="name">Hepp's Happy Burger Restaurant</span>
  <div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope 
       itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
Opening hours: Mo-Fri,
     <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" 
           href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday" />
     <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" 
           href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Tuesday" />
     <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" 
           href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Wednesday" />
     <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" 
           href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Thursday" />
     <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" 
           href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Friday" />
     <meta itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00">8:00 a.m. -
     <meta itemprop="closes" content="20:00:00">8:00 p.m.
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh! So the point is using `<link>`, not `<meta>`! Thanks a lot Martin. (and congrats for the vocabulary)

Comment: Please Martin, get also a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051258/microdata-and-multiple-opening-in-a-day).

Comment: Quick question -  which namespace(itemtype) should be used itemtype="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#OpeningHoursSpecification OR itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification" ?? Does it make any difference at all??

Comment: For classes and properties, use the GoodRelations elements in their schema.org namespace, e.g.  http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification. For instances, use the original GoodRelations namespace, e.g. http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#MasterCard. A list of those values is here: http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/goodrelations/v1.html#individuals Note that there are slight differences in the local parts of elements between the original GoodRelations namespace and the schema.org namespace, for a list, see here http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Cookbook/Schema.org#Naming_Differences