# Microdata and multiple opening in a day

Tags: microdata, schema.org

Suppose that a place does not offer the all-day-opening. Hence, we have two opening in one day.
How one should define the Microdata with [schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification)? 
I suppose that one should create two separated instances of *schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification* as follows:

```
Opening hours: 
  <div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope 
       itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">Mo,
     <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" 
           href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday" />
     <meta itemprop="opens" content="08:00:00">8:00 a.m. -
     <meta itemprop="closes" content="12:00:00">12:00 a.m.
  </div>
  <div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope 
       itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">Mo,
     <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" 
           href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday" />
     <meta itemprop="opens" content="16:00:00">4:00 a.m. -
     <meta itemprop="closes" content="20:00:00">8:00 p.m.
  </div>
```

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are exactly right!

If you want to understand the pattern, you can also play with the (kind of outdated) GoodRelations Annotator tool at

```
http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/tools/goodrelations-annotator/en/
```

It will generate respective RDFa markup for form-based input.

Note that in schema.org, the naming of elements may differ slightly from the naming in the original namespace, as documented here:

```
http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Cookbook/Schema.org#Naming_Differences
```

Best wishes

Martin Hepp